# .NET Core NU 1605

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I am trying to install nuget package of log4net on a project with dual frameworks (.Net Framework and .Net Core) and it gives me an error of NU 1605 Downgrade Package Detected.

I have seen solutions telling me to clear the field of "Treat warnings as errors" but currently I am looking at a different solution, if possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You have  to read the log messages, it says which packages are forced  to downgrade. This usually happens when you target a newer version of .NET Core but use libraries which depend on older version (i.e. you using .NET 5 where the library requires .NET Core 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [the official docs for NU1605](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605)?

It suggests adding a direct reference to the package in your project. This ensures NuGet's [nearest-wins rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins) always selects the version you have as a direct dependency.

If the package with the downgrade warning is only being restored in .NET Core, you can [use MSBuild condition statements to use the package only in one target framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition), although there's no way to do this using NuGet's Package Manager UI or Package Manager Console. You'll need to hand edit your project file to use this.